# SF novella or short story: Humans suddenly get the ability to grant their every wish

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, teleportation

People suddenly have the ability to materialise anything they desire, seemingly just by wishing for it.
This results in chaos, one example being that a young person materialises a ray gun and decimates his local.
It is finally discovered that they were not creating these items from nothing but simply teleporting them away from their owners, some being located elsewhere in the Galaxy.
This leads to Earth getting into trouble as a planet of thieves.
I may have read this in the 1980's or 1990's but I feel that it may be from much earlier.

Comment: "a young person materialises a ray gun and decimates his local" - what? Surely not the pub, what a git!

Comment: @DannyMcG. Probably missing an "e" at the end of "locale". But yes, that includes the pub too.

Answer (score 9):

Blindfold From The Stars by Philip E. High?  People suddenly develop mental powers. Turns out they had them in the far past, but they were blocked by aliens. Another alien race sends a virus, which cancels the blockage.

[This link to Amazon gives some of the plot details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0234721421)

Comment: This does have a scene where a teenager materialises a death-ray, but I don't think there is any thing about the Earth being regarded as a planet of thieves. Instead the Earth is a planet of supermen and their powers were originally suppressed out of fear of human powers.

Comment: @JohnRennie. Successful thieves *are* supermen